# How do I get all the values by key in set of anonymous hashes?

Tags: mongodb, perl

So I have

```
[{
   "name":"Hanna",
   "surname":"Miles"
},
{
   "name":"John",
   "surname":"Kenston"
}]
```

in my mongo dbase. I'm getting the info with:

`my $people = $self->mongo->get_collection('persons')`

How do I get a list of the names? So I need to get @result = ["Hanna", "John"] in this case.
Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi.  `get_collection` looks like a method on a database object to get a collection.  From a collection object, you'll actually need to run a query, which returns a cursor and from that you can iterate it to get results.  (Are you using the official MongoDB driver or a third-party driver?)

My point is that it's not clear if you've already done that and `$people` contains the *result* of a query as shown, but *as written*, `$people` isn't something you can just dereference for data in the database.

Answer (score 5):

To get exactly the output you want, you can use [map](http://p3rl.org/map):

```
my @result = [ map $_->{name}, @$people ];
```

But why do you want to have an anonymous array in an array?

```
my @result = map $_->{name}, @$people;
```

would create `@result = qw( Hanna John )`.

Comment: This is true is `$people` contains the array reference of hash references as shown.  But the OP's line of code implies that `$people` is a collection object, in which case this wouldn't work as the collection needs to be queried first.

Comment: @xdg: You're right, I totally overlooked the fact the presented JSON is the input to mongo, not the output of the query.